# Python script execution time increases when executed multiple time parallely

Tags: python, time

I have a python script whose execution time is 1.2 second while it is being executed standalone.

But when I execute it 5-6 time parallely ( Am using postman to ping the url multiple times) the execution time shoots up.

Adding the breakdown of the time taken.

```
1 run -> ~1.2seconds
2 run -> ~1.8seconds
3 run -> ~2.3seconds
4 run -> ~2.9seconds
5 run -> ~4.0seconds
6 run -> ~4.5seconds
7 run -> ~5.2seconds
8 run -> ~5.2seconds
9 run -> ~6.4seconds
10 run -> ~7.1seconds
```

Screenshot of top command(Asked in the comment):
[image]

This is a sample code:

```
import psutil
import os
import time
start_time = time.time()
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import numpy as np
import MySQLdb as mysql
import cv2
import sys
import rpy2.robjects as robj
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
R = robj.r
DTW = importr('dtw')

process= psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print " Memory Consumed after libraries load: "
print process.memory_info()[0]/float(2**20)

st_pt=4
# Generate our data (numpy arrays)
template = np.array([range(84),range(84),range(84)]).transpose()
query = np.array([range(2500000),range(2500000),range(2500000)]).transpose()


#time taken
print(" --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I also checked my memory consumption using `watch -n 1 free -m` and memory consumption also increases noticeably.

1) How do I make sure that the execution time of script remain constant everytime.

2) Can I load the libraries permanently so that the time taken by the script to load the libraries and the memory consumed can be minimized?

I made an enviroment and tried using

`#!/home/ec2-user/anaconda/envs/test_python/`

but it doesn't make any difference whatsoever.

**EDIT:**

I have AMAZON's EC2 server with 7.5GB RAM.

My php file with which am calling the python script.

```
<?php

    $response = array("error" => FALSE); 

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $command =escapeshellcmd(shell_exec("sudo /home/ec2-user/anaconda/envs/anubhaw_python/bin/python2.7 /var/www/cgi-bin/dtw_test_code.py"));
        session_write_close();
        $order=array("\n","\\");
        $cleanData=str_replace($order,'',$command);
        $response["message"]=$cleanData;

    } else 
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        $response["message"] = "Bad Request.";
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Without having too much knowledge about parallelization, I reckon that there is a certain threshold at which it is more effective to use parallelization. Maybe you are below that threshold due to the extensive loading time of the libraries.

Comment: I was under the impression that the environment serves that purpose i.e make an enviro and load all the required libraries in that and use that environment everywhere. But I think that is not the case. What can I do here?

Comment: *1) How do I make sure that the execution time of script remain constant everytime.* <= you cannot. As far as I can see, your operations are mostly memory bound and --my guess-- your CPUs are sharing the same memory bus. So RAM bandwidth is probably the bottleneck.

Comment: I have amazon ec2 server and I got 7.5GB of RAM and using the command `watch -n 1 free -m` , i can see that each execution takes almost 300MB. So I guess, If I run even 10 of them simultaneously, enough RAM resources will be available for them to execute.  So atleast for 10 of them, the execution time should be same. Right?

Comment: What [type of EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) is this being run on?

Comment: m3.large is the type.

Comment: You are getting a 200 times slow-down from running 5 processes in parallel.  Even if you were CPU bound (either through bus or processing instructions) it just doesn't add up...  Can you check your python process memory and CPU stats, e.g. using top, instead of relying on `free`?

Comment: Added the snapshot of top command.

Comment: Why do you need PHP in your example? I came up with a bunch of solutions in my answer but this point still seems vague to me

Comment: @ffeast Well, python framework was not available at that time and I was ready to change my framework for it too but then I figured out that the issue which am having, is not something which is only coz of using php or it'll go away if I use python framework. I wonder how big tech companies handle heavy computation in real-time.

Answer (score 3):

1) You really can't ensure the execution will take always the same time, but at least you can avoid performance degradation by using a "locking" strategy like the ones described in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/22006).

Basically you can test if the lockfile exists, and if so, put your program to sleep a certain amount of time, then try again.

If the program does not find the lockfile, it creates it, and delete the lockfile at the end of its execution.

Please note: in the below code, when the script fails to get the lock for a certain number of `retries`, it will exit (but this choice is really up to you).

The following code exemplifies the use of a file as a "lock" against parallel executions of the same script.

```
import time
import os
import sys

lockfilename = '.lock'
retries = 10
fail = True

for i in range(retries):
    try:
        lock = open(lockfilename, 'r')
        lock.close()
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception:
        print('Got after {} retries'.format(i))
        fail = False
        lock = open(lockfilename, 'w')
        lock.write('Locked!')
        lock.close()
        break

if fail:
    print("Cannot get the lock, exiting.")
    sys.exit(2)

# program execution...
time.sleep(5)
# end of program execution

os.remove(lockfilename)
```

2) This would mean that different python instances share the same memory pool and I think it's not feasible.

Comment: I tried you code and it's doing what you explained. But the thing is, I have the python script as an API i.e I call the php file passing some parameters and then python executes that to give some output. The locking makes sure that while one code is executing, the other keep try for the lock and if it's free, then execute the script. But it's totally different of what I want to achieve. I want that python script to execute parallel to the one which is already executing as I have the RAM resources available.

Comment: Right. And you want it to take the same amount of time; which sounds a bit strange, because execution doesn't mean RAM only, but also CPU, disk swapping and task switching (almost all of them handled by the OS, which gives you less control). The way I suggested made execution time linear (i.e. if 1 script = 1 second, 2 scripts = 2 seconds, etc.).

Comment: But if am using this as an API then for 100 users, then the request for those 100 users will get completed linearly, i.e one by one. This is exactly what I don't want. I want to process the req of those 100 users simultaneously. Considering your point that there are multiple parameters on which the execution time depends, it shouldn't be 3 times the normal execution time. Right?

Comment: No, not at all. If you processed 100 requests simultaneously, the PHP script would spawn 100 parallel shell commands, and the way you implemented it, each shell command would allocate 300 Mb of RAM (which makes 30Gb, thus swapping to disk and incrementing execution time dramatically).

Comment: As of now am working with 5 req only. So 5*300=1.5GB and I have 7.5GB on my server. I got 8GB of disk space and almost 80% of it's free. Isn't this  a sort of favorable condition for the system? P.S. I totally understand your point and I agree to it but am trying to figure out this weird behavior in my case. It shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 2):

### Here's what we have:

- EC2 instance  type is m3.large box which has only **2** vCPUs https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/?nc1=h_ls
- We need to run a CPU- and memory-hungry script which takes over a second to execute when CPU is not busy
- You're building an API than needs to handle concurrent requests and running apache
- From the screenshot I can conclude that:

  - your CPUs are 100% utilized when 5 processes are run. Most likely they    would be 100% utilized even when fewer processes are run. So this is the bottleneck and no surprise that the more processes are run the more time is required — you CPU resources just get shared among concurrently running scripts.
  - each script copy eats about ~300MB of RAM so you have lots of spare RAM and it's not a bottleneck. The amount of free + buffers memory on your screenshot confirms that.
- The missing part is:

  1. are requests directly sent to your apache server or there's a balancer/proxy in front of it?
  2. why do you need PHP in your example? There are plently of solutions available using python ecosystem only without a php wrapper ahead of it

### Answers to your questions:

> 1. That's infeasible in general case

The most you can do is to track your CPU usage and make sure its idle time doesn't drop below some empirical threshold — in this case your scripts would be run in more or less fixed amount of time.

To guarantee that you need to limit the number of  requests being processed concurrently. 
But if 100 requests are sent to your API concurrently you won't be able to handle them all in parallel! Only some of them will be handled in parallel while others waiting for their turn. But your server won't be knocked down trying to serve them all.

> 2. Yes and no

**No** because unlikely can you do something in your present architecture when a new script is launched on every request through a php wrapper. BTW it's a very expensive operation to run a new script from scratch each time.

**Yes** if a different solution is used. Here are the options:

- use a python-aware *pre-forking* webserver which will handle your requests directly. You'll spare CPU resources on python startup + you might utilize some preloading technics to share RAM among workers, i.e http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#preload-app. You'd also need to limit the number of parallel workers to be run http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#workers to adress your first requirement.
- if you need **PHP** for some reason you might setup some *intermediary* between **PHP** script and python workers — i.e. a *queue*-like server.
  Than simply run several instances of your *python* scripts which would wait for some request to be availble in the queue. Once it's available it would handle it and put the response back to the *queue* and php script would slurp it and return back to the client. But it's a more complex to build this that the first solution (if you can eliminate your PHP script of course) and more components would be involved.
- reject the idea to handle such heavy requests concurrently, and instead assign each request a **unique id**, put the request into a *queue* and return this id to the client immediately. The request will be picked up by an offline handler and put back into the *queue* once it's finished. It will be client's responsibility to poll your API for readiness of this particular request
- 1st and 2nd combined — handle requests in **PHP** and request another HTTP server (or any other TCP server) handling your preloaded .py-scripts

Answer (score 2):

1)

## More servers equals more availability

Hearsay tells me that one effective way to ensure consistent request times is to use multiple requests to a cluster. As I heard it the idea goes something like this.

#### The chance of a slow request

<sub>(Disclaimer I'm not much of a mathematician or statistician.)</sub>

If there is a 1% chance a request is going to take an abnormal amount of time to finish then one-in-a-hundred requests can be expected to be slow. If you as a client/consumer make two requests to a cluster instead of just one, the chance that both of them turn out to be slow would be more like  1/10000, and with three 1/1000000, et cetera. The downside is doubling your incoming requests means needing to provide (and pay for) as much as twice the server power to fulfill your requests with a consistent time, this additional cost scales with how much chance is acceptable for a slow request.

To my knowledge this concept is optimized for consistent fulfillment times.

#### The client

A client interfacing with a service like this has to be able to spawn multiple requests and handle them gracefully, probably including closing the unfulfilled connections as soon as it can.

#### The servers

On the backed there should be a load balancer that can associate multiple incoming client requests to multiple unique cluster workers. If a single client makes multiple requests to an overburdened node, its just going to compound its own request time like you see in your simple example.

In addition to having the client opportunistically close connections it would be best to have a system of sharing job fulfilled status/information so that backlogged request on other other slower-to-process nodes have a chance of aborting an already-fulfilled request.

---

This this a rather informal answer, I do not have direct experience with optimizing a service application in this manner. If someone does I encourage and welcome more detailed edits and expert implementation opinions.

---

2)

## Caching imports

yes that is a thing, and its awesome!

I would personally recommend setting up django+gunicorn+nginx. Nginx can cache static content and keep a request backlog, gunicorn provides application caching and multiple threads&worker management (not to mention awesome administration and statistic tools), django embeds best practices for database migrations, auth, request routing, as well as off-the-shelf plugins for providing semantic rest endpoints and documentation, all sorts of goodness.

If you really insist on building it from scratch yourself you should study [uWsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), a great [Wsgi implementation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) that can be interfaced with [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) to provide application caching. Gunicorn isn't the only option either, Nicholas Piël has a [Great write up](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers) comparing performance of various python web serving apps.

Answer (score 1):

The ec2 cloud does not guarantee 7.5gb of free memory on the server.  This would mean that the VM performance is severely impacted like you are seeing where the server has less than 7.5gb of physical free ram.  Try reducing the amount of memory the server thinks it has.

This form of parallel performance is very expensive.  Typically with 300mb requirement, the ideal would be a script which is long running, and re-uses the memory for multiple requests.  The Unix fork function allows a shared state to be re-used.  The `os.fork` gives this in python, but may not be compatible with your libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the way computers are run.

Each program gets a **slice of time on a computer** (quote [***Help Your Kids With Computer Programming***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/146541956X), say maybe ***1/1000* of a second**)

***Answer 1***: Try using multiple ***[threads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects)*** instead of **parallel processes**.

It'll be less **time-consuming**, but the program's **time to execute** still won't be completely **constant**.

***Note:*** Each program has it's own slot of **memory**, so that is why **memory consumption** is shooting up.